# Rails nested dynamic page based on ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Basic question — I'm trying to create a new view that would appear at a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/students/4/profile
```

Currently I have show.html.erb which would go here:

```
http://localhost:3000/students/4
```

What do I need to put in my routes.rb (which is currently what's below) to allow me to create a custom page like that?

```
resources :students
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Routing Section of the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions): you can use the `member` method within a resource block to define a member route/action

```
resources :students do
  member do  
    get :profile
  end
end
```

This would define a `students/:id/profile` route that would map to a `profile` method on your students controller.